# SQL query to find duration based on several criteria

Tags: sql

I have a table named `status` with following data in it:

```
time       var  value
12:00:01    a   10
12:00:01    b   10
12:00:01    c   12
12:00:05    a   9
12:00:05    b   10
12:00:05    c   10
12:00:10    a   13
12:00:10    b   1
12:00:10    c   4
14:00:01    a   12
14:00:01    b   11
14:00:01    c   9
14:00:41    a   9
14:00:41    b   9
14:00:41    c   3
```

Now I want to find the duration for which `A > 10` and `B > 10`
I want the answer as: 44 sec (duration from 12:00:01 to 12:00:05 = 4 sec, duration from 14:00:01 to 14:00:41 = 40 sec, total 44 sec)
I tried:

```
SELECT sum(time) as duration FROM status WHERE A>10 AND B>10;
```

Comment: Please only tag a single RDBMS

Comment: What if a > 10 happens at 14:00:01 and b > 10 happens at 14:00:05?  Do you take the earliest time to base the calculation off?

Comment: Three variables occur at same time. Like sensor entry

Comment: At `12:00:01` a=10 and b=10, not a>10 and b>10.

Comment: You think you have explained yourself well, but haven't.

Comment: This is a "Gaps & Islands" problem. The SQL solution requires the use of window functions with a full frames implementation. Only a handful of databases implement it, so it's critical you specify which one you are using.

Comment: What the data type of the columns?

Answer (score 0):

This is a gaps and islands problem, which can be solved using a cumulative sum.  The `lag()` is used to determine where islands start.  The cumulative sum defines groups.

SQL date/time functions are notoriously database-dependent.  So the following gives the right idea, but it may not work directly in your database.  So, the times when the condition occurs is returned by the following query:

```
select min(time), max(time)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when a < 10 or b < 10 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by time) as grp
      from status t
     ) t
where a > 10 and b > 10;
```

The `sum()` is then an aggregation on this.  For instance:

```
select sum(maxtime - mintime)
from (select max(time) as maxtime, min(time) as mintime
      from (select t.*,
                   sum(case when a < 10 or b < 10 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by time) as grp
            from status t
           ) t
      where a > 10 and b > 10
     ) t
```

Comment: @hslkfvc . . . "SQL throws error" is of no use.  You need specify what the error is.

Comment: how will a>10 and b>10 works when both are from different columns

Comment: @hslkfvc . . . They *are* from different columns.  That question makes no sense.